# Constant multiplication and addition of functions in Linearity

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I read so about linearity:

> A map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is called linear if it satisfies
>
> - $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$
> - $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Is there any function such that it satisfies condition 1 but not condition 2 or vice versa? If possible, please give examples for both cases...

Comment: If exists such a function will be non-linear. Then, clearly a non-linear function will fail both conditions at some $x$ and $y$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

For the first case, such functions called homogenous functions and for the second they called additive function, the function below is homogenous but not additive

$f:(\mathbb{R}^*_+)^3$ $\rightarrow$ $ \mathbb{R}^3 $

$(x,y,z)$  $\rightarrow$  $f(x,y,z)=(\frac{z^2}{y},\frac{x^2}{z},\frac{y^2}{x}) $

Comment: Thanks. Please provide an example for the vice versa also if possible. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous then the first condition implies the second condition. However if $f$ is not continuous then the first condition implies $f(rx)=rf(x)$ for $r\in\Bbb{Q}$.